# Laravel unique validation with slug

Tags: php, laravel

I have two options, either the users gives a custom unique_id and I convert it via `Str::slug($request->custom)` or it gets generated via `Str::random(6)`

My code:

```
$post = new Post;
$unique_id = Str::random(6);
$idcustom = Str::slug($request->custom);

$this->validate($request, [
   'custom'     => 'max:25|string|unique:posts,unique_id' . Str::slug($post->unique_id),
]);
```

If the user creates the custom id, `$idcustom` gets inserted into the database, if he just leaves the field empty `$unique_id` gets inserted. But if there is already an entry with for example "stack overflow" I get an SQL error, that there is already an entry with that name, but if its like "stackoverflow" it works like it should. So it has to do with the slug, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why does it work when the custom id has NO whitespace inside but not when it has whitespace, which ```Str::slug()``` converts into -?

Comment: I just checked the docs, you cannot pass a value to the unique rule, only the id that should be ignored. So you would have to transform the value from the request before it gets validated, that is why "stackoverflow" fails and "stack overflow" passes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put 'fallback' values into the validation rules. You'd perhaps want to check `$request->custom` manually before swapping it with your random string?

Not sure whether this'll help... your question is not clear on whether you're creating a new user or updating an existing one. If updating an existing one, don't forget to exclude from checking against the current user:

```
'custom' => ['max:25', 'string',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
```